# adminLTE gap between content-wrapper and top bar

Tags: html, asp.net, dom, adminlte

I'm using adminLte template, my problem is there is a gap between my content page and the top bar. please see below image. I tried many times for like 1 to two hours to find out what is that element but can't find it in inspect element it's unselectable. Any idea will be appreciated. thank you
description: 
Blue: topbar(nav bar)
             Red: Content Page
             Black/DarkGray: It is the problem, it's the gap between the nav var and content. I want my nav bar and content to be placed next to each other ,in other words no margin between those two elements.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this issue is most likely the standard site css template which the adminLTE isn't overriding.

You can try removing the following code from your Site.css file which is in your Content folder

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

On a further note, there is a GitHub repository which you can pull into your current project which can be found here https://github.com/eralston/AdminLteMvc

Comment: thank you! I got an idea from your answer. On my aspx I set padding-top: 1px and it fits exactly. Will do more testing later. thanks mate!